# How to re-use Cucumber steps in different projects?

Tags: automation, cucumber

I have a project with login and other functionalities tests in Cucumber. There are different projects which use the same login function. I would like to reuse the cucumber login steps from one project to another project.

Eg:

Project1->TestLogin1

Project2->TestLogin1

Answer (score 0):

In general don't try and do this. Cucumber scenarios should describe the behaviour of your system and their implementation should be specific to each particular system. People have been trying to do this in the cukes community for years, generally with little success.

Sure with something as simple as login you could share ... until one application starts allowing you to register by Facebook whilst the other requires you to confirm via email.

In practice the amount you save in sharing (which is very small) if offset by the amount you lose in being able to make you scenarios specific to the world of your application.

Comment: Well in this case if we could share the test code, we would save considerable amount of time by avoiding repetitive work

Comment: As I said people have being trying to do this for over a decade. Yes you can get some short term gains which initially seem attractive. But this gains are quickly overtaken by the negatives. In testing often a little repetition is the best option. I mean how long does it take you to write cukes to do registration and login even a slow poke like me can do that in just a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely benefit from sharing step definitions between projects, because there is likely to be a lot of overlap between certain parts of an app, such as admin tasks.

If you use an IDE for feature editing, you may then be able to benefit from leveraging those step defs through autocomplete.

It should be possible to package step defs into repos that are then included by module.  You might be able to leverage tags or hooks to aid in setup so the context is correct.

Whether it’s worth the effort of coordinating across many projects will likely depend on your use case.